# searching in mysql results

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a question or maybe misconception about seraching in Mysql.

---

In my table I have 2 fields, first's `ID` (int 8) and second's `used` (int 1).

The `used` field just get 0 or 1 like boolean.

Assuming the number of rows's 20001,

**about `ID`: My last ID is 20001 and first ID's 1.**

**about `used`: Just my first row which has ID = 1 is 1 and the others is 0.**

Now when I wanna get one row, I write this code.It's OK.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM  `table` 
 WHERE  `used` =0
 LIMIT 0 , 1
```

I just want a row with 0 amount in `used`.
But my problem is : I imagine, Mysql search all of the 20000 rows, and so give me one row. This will hurt me because I just want one row with 0 amount in `used`
what's the best way for doing?

Comment: I don't think that query will go through all 20000 rows. Most likely it will go rows one by one checking the conditions and when the limit will be full it will stop. The problem may appear when you will be using sorting on columns that are not indexed.

Comment: please more clearify your question

Comment: @Zefiryn Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE used = "0";
```

Will give you all rows which used value is 0, with:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE used = "0" LIMIT 1;
```

Will give you one row which used value is 0.

If this is not what you are looking for, can you clarify your question?

If you need the last record

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE used = "0" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**Edit:**

If you are worried about speed of your queries I suspect that if you start up your mysql via command line (or tool you prefer) and run queries provided to a table with only that much records you will get sentence saying how long it will take, it might say (0.00 sec) if its absolutely nothing. :)

If your table gets more complicated consider learning to use mysql indexes for certain columns: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

**About reserved words in MySQL:**

Your table naming caught my attention and you should consider of using something other than `table` as table name so you don't need to use quotation marks around table word when using it. (you are also using them around word `used` which is not even reserved word.

List of reserved words which should be avoided to be used within MySQL(5.5): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thank you, But my question's about performane.
I want a row, Is this a Best sql code for getting One row?

Comment: @wandad yes it is, your table is so simple that it doesn't need indexing your columns.

Comment: @wandad updated my answer to contain useful information to your case.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the very first match and the search will stop when it finds the first match.

**1.**

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM `table`
WHERE `used`=0
 OR NOT (EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM `table` WHERE `used`=0))
ORDER BY ASCENDING;
```

**2.**

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `used`=0
 OR NOT (EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM `table` WHERE `used`=0))
ORDER BY ASCENDING LIMIT 1;
```

Both do the same thing, run your tests and see which one executes faster.

Comment: If you set the `limit` to `1` it will stop searching after the very first match. @wandad

Comment: I've tried your code, But the Query took was 0.0006 sec, It means your code and my code are the same.
Do you agree?

Comment: @wandad side note: if your query took only around 0.0006 sec its practically nothing at all.

Comment: @wandad, checkout the revision above.